# How can I express a vector in a different affine basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, euclidean-geometry

Consider the setup in the figure below.

[image]

There are three different coordinate frames: A, B, and C. Frame A can be thought of as the "global" frame, which means that the location and orientation of frames B and C are expressed relative to frame A. That is, frame B is translated by the green vector and rotated counterclockwise by $\theta_B$ radians with respect to frame A. Similarly, frame C is translated by the orange vector and rotated counterclockwise by $\theta_C$ radians with respect to frame A ($\theta_C$ can be greater than or less than $\theta_B$; my drawing is only an illustration). I am given the blue vector, which corresponds to the coordinates of the vector $x$ with respect to frame B, as well as the green and orange vectors. My objective is to determine the coordinates of the vector $x$ with respect to frame C (that is, to determine the red vector).

Here is what I tried so far: the vector $x$ has three different coordinate vectors associated with it: one for frame A, which is $v_A$ (not drawn above and not given), one for frame B, which is $R_{\theta_B}v_B + t_B$ ($v_B$ should be the blue vector), and one for frame C, which is $R_{\theta_C}v_C + t_C$ ($v_C$ should be the red vector), where
$$
R_\theta = \begin{bmatrix}\cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) \\ \sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta)\end{bmatrix}
$$
corresponds to a 2D rotation counterclockwise by $\theta$ and $R_\theta^{-1}$ is its inverse that corresponds to a clockwise rotation by $\theta$, $t_B$ corresponds to the green vector, and $t_C$ corresponds to the orange vector. Therefore, to obtain the coordinates of $x$ with respect to frame C, we solve for $v_C$ as follows:
\begin{align}
R_{\theta_B}v_B + t_B &= R_{\theta_C}v_C + t_C \\
R_{\theta_B}v_B + t_B - t_C &= R_{\theta_C}v_C \\
R_{\theta_C}^{-1}(R_{\theta_B}v_B + t_B - t_C) &= v_C \\
\end{align}
I'm not sure about this reasoning, so I would appreciate any feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more thought, I think this reasoning is indeed correct. To better understand why, we will consider a related but simpler example. Consider the setup shown in Fig. 1 below.

[image]

#### Fig. 1

There are two different frames, A and B, where A is considered to be the "global" frame. We have two different expressions for the vector $v$: one in frame A, which is represented by the coordinate vector $y$, and one in frame B, which is represented by the coordinate vector $w$ (note that a *vector* $v$ is an element of some vector space, while its associated [*coordinate vector*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_vector) is its representation with respect to some basis that is chosen from the same vector sapce, in this case the basis vectors associated with either frame A ($y$) or frame B ($w$)).

We want to determine the relationship between the coordinate vectors $y$ and $w$. That is, how do we go from $w$ to $y$, and vice versa, via some rotation and translation. To do so, we will proceed as follows. First, consider frame A only, as shown in Fig. 2 below.

[image]

#### Fig. 2

We consider the basis vectors associated with frame A to be the standard basis vectors $e_1$ and $e_2$. Then, we can construct the vector $v$ by taking a specific linear combination of the vectors $e_1$ and $e_2$. Let this linear combination be represented by the coordinate vector $y$. This amounts to computing $v = Iy$, where $I$ is the $2 \times 2$ identity matrix, as shown in Fig. 3 below.

[image]

#### Fig. 3

Going back to frame A, we can rotate each of the basis vectors associated with frame A counterclockwise by $\theta_B$ to get frame B before it is translated, as shown in Fig. 4 below. Because the basis vectors associated with frame A are $e_1$ and $e_2$, then this amounts to computing $R_{\theta_B} I$, where $R_{\theta_B}$ is the $2 \times 2$ rotation matrix that corresponds to a counterclockwise rotation by $\theta_B$.

[image]

#### Fig. 4

Using this rotated frame, we can compute some linear combination of its basis vectors to compute the vector $z$. Let this linear combination be represented by the coordinate vector $w$ (which is the same $w$ shown in Fig. 1 above). This is equivalent to computing $z = R_{\theta_B} I w$, as shown in Fig. 5 below.

[image]

#### Fig. 5

Finally, we compute the vector $v$ by translating the coordinate vector associated with $z$ by the coordinate vector $t$, as shown in Fig. 6 below ($t$ also has an abstract vector equivalent that is independent of a basis, but that's another story). This is equivalent to computing $v = R_{\theta_B} I w + t = Iy$.

[image]

#### Fig. 6

We therefore have the following relationship between $w$ and $y$: $$R_{\theta_B} w + t = y$$
Relating this back to the question, we have the following relationship (note that frame A is the global frame):
\begin{align}
x &= Iv_A \\
&= R_{\theta_B} I v_B + t_B \\
&= R_{\theta_C} I v_C + t_C
\end{align}
which can be used to solve for $v_C$ in terms of $v_B$. Note that the simpler example given above is just the special case when $t_C = 0$ and $\theta_C = 0$. Also, note that
$$
\begin{align}
R_{\theta_C}^{-1}R_{\theta_B} &= R_{\theta_B - \theta_C} \\
R_{\theta_C}^{-1} &= R_{\theta_C}^T
\end{align}
$$